# How can I setup a DMZ with iptables while retaining web browsing/etc. capabilities on the router?

Tags: iptables, firewall

Ok, so I have the following setup:

- A raspberry pi is connected to both my LAN (wifi on `iface0`) and a computer (ethernet on `iface1`).
- The computer provides a handful of services including some that get started on random ports (rpcbind, but also services only started as needed).

I would like to forward these services from `iface1` to `iface0` (in a DMZ fashion). Said otherwise, the RPi would act as a transparent proxy...

The problem is that the raspberry pi also needs to access the LAN by itself and some services (SSH most notably) must not be forwarded.

Is there a way to effectively forward all ports except SSH to `iface0` while retaining the ability of browsing the web, etc. from the raspberry pi? It seems to me that if I try to access a website from the raspberry pi, the answer would be forwarded to the other computer as well...

Answer (score 0):

A transparent firewall might make sense here. Traffic from the firewall itself should romp through the `OUTPUT` chain (or directly to the firewall via the `INPUT` chain) distinct from the `FORWARD` chain used to shuffle packets over the bridge between the two interfaces. The firewall would have its IP on the `br0` interface.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10929

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ethernet_plus_WiFi_Bridge_Router_and_Firewall

Comment: Seems like **transparent firewall** was the good naming :)

Comment: @Jacomo it might however be problematical if one interface needs NAT because of an ISP, as with this setup your subnet is on both sides of the firewall (hence the transparent thing...)

Comment: I really just need to be able to access the internet (through the dumb router the RPi is connected to) from the RPi and the other persons in the LAN should be able to access the services provided by the computer behind the RPi by accessing the RPi itself.

Comment: Ah... I see what you meant: basically the router sees 2 MAC addresses which does not work in this case... :/